# How do I click a JLabel using MouseListener?

Tags: java, label, jlabel, mouselistener

I am trying to make this program for minecraft, and now im just getting started. I want that if you click a label, it will check what label is it and will do something.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 

            System.out.println(me.getX()+", "+me.getY()+"."); 
            Object source = me.getSource();
            int intx =  me.getX();
            int inty = me.getY();

            if(me.getX()>=1 && me.getY()>=1 && me.getX()<=70 && me.getY()<=45){
                permissionsframe.setLocation(810,250);
                System.out.println(p1p.length);
                permissionsframe.pack();
                permissionsframe.setSize(200, 200);
                permissionsframe.setVisible(true);
                JLabel playerperms = new JLabel("Player "+p1s+" has "+p1p.length+" permissions.");
                playerperms.setBounds(1, 1, 150, 150);
                permissionsframe.add(playerperms);
                System.out.println("You chose "+player1.getText()+".");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You did not click any label.");
            }

        }
    });
```

This selection area is adapted to the name I have now - NonameSL. But if the name will be longer or shorter, the selection area will obviuosly be different...

Is there a way to get the excact label? I tried `if(source.equals(player1))`(Player 1 is the label) but I placed the label in 1, 1 and I have to click the excact point that I defined the label in, X=1, Y=1. How can I make a mouse listener listen to a label?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check if the mouse coordinates are inside your JLabel.
You can bind a Listener to every JLabel an process the click/press event in your `MyMouseListener.class`

To do so:

You have to add the MouseListener to every JLabel:

```
MyMouseListener myMouseListener = new MyMouseListener();

label01.setName("name01");
label01.addMouseListener(myMouseListener);

label02.setName("name02");
label02.addMouseListener(myMouseListener);
```

To identify the JLabel you could do something like this:

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         JLabel l = (JLabel) e.getSource();

         if(l.getName().equals("name01"))
             doSomething01();
         else if(l.getName().equals("name02"))
             doSomething02();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that does not work. My code is: http://pastebin.com/h9zAD2Df When I run the code, it waits a few seconds, and then THIS error shows up: (Its too long for stackoverflow, here it is in pastebin) :http://pastebin.com/CEq8KegY

Comment: If you want to go this way it's better to use the command pattern to perform the actions.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use the `.getComponent()` method instead of the `.getSource()` since this is **MouseEvent** which is something different than **ActionEvent**.

Implement the Listener to your class:

```
public class Main implements MouseListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //setup JFrame and some label and then 

    label.addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getComponent().equals(label)) {

        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
}
//the other orderride methods..
```